# Excluding specific iPhone types from App Store submission

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I created a SpriteKit game that needs large screen area to be played so I decided not to write the code for the iPhone SE, but now I'm not sure if I can submit it to the App Store for all devices except the SE. Please let me know whether it's possible, and if so how to do it (i.e. where on iTunes Connect would you do it).

I looked up a lot but I couldn't find anything that could help.
I also couldn't find anything in the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no support from Apple for this kind of thing. But you can do something like detecting whether the user's device is an iPhone SE and if so show a full screen alert saying "App is not supported for this device" and block the UI (which is not recommended unless it's required).

**Just a thought:**
If you are lucky to find out one device capability which distinguish iPhone SE, you can set that to value in **UIDeviceRequiredCapabilities** key in info.plist.

Example: Adding an item to UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in your Info.plist with the requirement of "bluetooth-le" should limit your app to iPhone 4S/5 and iPad 3, 4 and mini. You could also throw in a "camera-flash" requirement to limit the app to iPhones only, should you need that.

*More info:* [Device Compatibility Matrix](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW1)

Comment: Am i allowed to show this message on my app or will it be rejected

Comment: I don't think it will be rejected. I tried in one of my apps. It's worked.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot exclude certain devices. You can exclude iPad/iPhone, or require a minimum iOS version.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude iPhone SE, you can add `UIDeviceRequiredCapabilities` of `nfc`.
Pay attention this will allow only iPhone 7 devices and above.

Answer (score 0):

Apple filters your app on 2 bases -

1. iOS Version
2. Universal or iPhone/iPad

You can not avoid any specific iPhone model based on the screen size if you have created an app for iPhone.